# Run a query based on output of another query

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have 3 queries based on first result i have to execute the 2 or 3rd query

If the output is 2 i have to eexute 2nd query

If the op is 3 then 3rd query

pls help

Comment: Please show the 1, 2 and 3 queries and what you have attempted.

Comment: just select op from table1  2nd query just select columnname from table2  select id  from table3

Comment: Sounds like two left joins might give you something close. You'd get better answers if you show evidence of trying to work it out yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT   XX,  
     CASE 
     WHEN Y =  1 THEN (Select X from table2 where xx= )
     WHEN Y = 2 THEN  (Select X from table3 where xx=)
  END 
   FROM table1
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: am tryign the same code but am unable to use limit or rownum in subquery Thanks for ur reply

Comment: In Sql Server, The same query i tried with top and it works fine.

Comment: @MusicLovingIndianGirl am getting Incorrect syntax near ')'

Comment: Yes worked now before i have 2 columns in when statement once I change it started working